# php dom problem

Tags: php

hello I'm new to PHP programming and I migrated from ASP .net to PHP..

I have a div just like below

`<div id="mydiv"></div>`

what I wanted to do is just to change the text and html content(like some name or any data in it) in it.

What I imagine is just like

mydiv=>innertext="some value";

Thanks,
GURU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to modify the div in the same page as the php? I don't think that's possible.

PHP runs at the server, and only sees content between the php tags.

If you're modifying dom content, it seems like javascript/jQuery is a better approach for this.

Otherwise, if you're modifying content that is hosted already, and plan output it to a different page, then you can use this:

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for your information Alan,

i appreciate you.
Thanks again.
Guru

Answer (score 0):

$myDivText = "This is what goes inside mydiv";

echo "<div id=\"mydiv\">$myDivText</div>";

Comment: Thanks for your information but I couldn't got your means.

Though I've already got a right answers, anyways thanks again for taking interest in my query.

:)